# Different font-sizes in SASS box?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a box made in HTML and SASS.  The html looks like this:

```
<main>
 <ul>
     <li><span>1<br>£200</span></li>
</ul>
</main>
```

And the key SASS looks like this:

```
body{
 font-family: Avenir, Heveltica, sans-serif;
}  
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 10vw);
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  min-height: 90vh;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 1px);
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  span {
    margin-top: 0.4rem;
  }  
}
```

However I want the second line (after the break) to be a different font size to the first!  I have no idea how to do this though.  Grateful for your help!

Comment: Could you please post the actual HTML instead of just some text? It would help us a lot.

Comment: Woops, that was a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

So there is a way to target the first line in CSS so to target the second line do something like this:

```
li span {
    /* this targets the whole span but just override it for the first line below */
    font-size: 20px;
}

li span:first-line {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```